# If-else statement?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to calculate values of Ct for a 9x1 array using the following equations. I have edited my question to show my current code:

```
% Inputs
R=0.4;                                          % Radius of Rotor
B=3;                                            % Number of blades
V=2;                                            % Fluid velocity
Rho=998;                                        % Fluid Density
N=9;                                            % Number of Blade Elements
Cp_estimate=0.5;                                % Estimate power coefficient
Alpha_design=4;                                 % Design alpha
Cl_design=1;                                    % Design lift coefficient

% Variables
TSR=1;                                          % Initial tip speed ratio
Cp=0;                                           % Initial power coefficient
i=1;                                            % Counter
alpha_new=0;                                    % Initial value for alpha new
axial_induction=0;                              % Initial axial induction factor
tolerance=0.01;                                 % Tolerance Value
Check=1;                                        % Initial check value
axial_induction_old=0;                          % Initial value for old axial induction factor

Cl=[1.3; 1.1; 1; 0.9; 0.86; 0.83; 0.8; 0.75; 0.5];                                          % Lift Coefficients
Cd=[0.027; 0.024; 0.02; 0.019; 0.018; 0.016; 0.013; 0.012; 0.01];                           % Drag Coefficients

r_local=R/N*(1:9)';
r_over_R=r_local / R;


for TSR=1:10                                     % TSR from 1 to 10
  disp(TSR)                                                                    
  Check=1;
  Cp=0;   

  while abs(Check)>=tolerance
    TSR_local=r_over_R .* TSR;

    Phi=(2/3)*atan(1./TSR_local);
    C=((8*pi.*r_local) ./ (B.*Cl_design)).*(1-cos(Phi));
    sigma=(B*C) ./ (pi.*r_local.*2);

    axial_induction= 1 ./ (((4.*(sin(Phi).^2)) ./ (sigma.*Cl_design.*cos(Phi)))+1);
    angular_induction= (1-(3*axial_induction)) ./ ((4.*axial_induction)-1);

    axial_induction_old = axial_induction;        
    TSR_local = TSR .* (r_local./R);                                                                 % Local Tip Speed Ratio
    Phi = (2/3) .* atan(1./TSR_local);                                                               % Angle of Relative Fluid

    relative_wind = atan((1-axial_induction) ./ ((1+angular_induction) .* TSR));

    F=(2/pi) .* acos(exp(-(((B/2) .* (1-(r_over_R))) ./ ((r_over_R) .* sin(relative_wind)))));      % Tip Loss Factor

    C_T=(sigma .* ((1-axial_induction).^2) .* ((Cl.*cos(relative_wind))+(Cd.*sin(relative_wind)))) ./ ((sin(relative_wind)).^2);

    for i=1:length(C_T)
      if C_T(i)<=0.96
        axial_induction(i)=1 ./ (1+(4.*F.*(sin(relative_wind).^2)) ./ (sigma.*Cl.*cos(relative_wind))); 
      elseif C_T(i)>0.96
        axial_induction(i)=1 ./ (((4.*F.*cos(relative_wind)) ./ (sigma.*Cl))-1);
      end
    end

    D=(8./(TSR.*N)).*(F.*(sin(Phi).^2).*(cos(Phi)-((TSR_local).*(sin(Phi)))).*(sin(Phi)+((TSR_local).*(cos(Phi)))).*(1-(Cd./Cl).*atan(Phi)).*(TSR_local.^2));
    Cp=sum(D);

    Diff=axial_induction-axial_induction_old;
    Check=max(Diff(:));

  end

  store_Phi(:,TSR)=Phi;
  store_TSR_local(:,TSR)=TSR_local;
  store_axial_induction(:,TSR)=axial_induction;
  store_angular_induction(:,TSR)=angular_induction;
  store_relative_wind(:,TSR)=relative_wind;
  store_Check(:,TSR)=Check;
  store_Diff(:,TSR)=Diff;
  store_Cp(:,TSR)=Cp;
  store_TSR(:,TSR)=TSR;

end
```

As u can see the equation for axial induction changes depending on whether the calculated CT value is greater or lower than 0.96. However I am unsure about my if else statement as it appears to not be working? Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: What if `C_T=0.96`? Won't that condition ever occur? Or nothing to do in that case? Otherwise we need to look into the actual mathematical equation you have.

Comment: Thank you for our reply, I have changed my code for the event that CT = 0.96. However I am wondering if my if statement was written correctly as I am still a novice at Matlab and the programme appear to ignore it?

Comment: C_T isn't a single number, right? It is a `9x1` vector of numbers?

Comment: Yes it is a 9x1 vector of numbers. I also received the warning at my if-else statement to say that CT may be set by a nonscalar operator. Any ideas?

Comment: So, if `size(C_T)` is `9,1`, how can you compare it to single number? Either use `any(C_T < 0.96)`, or compute `axial_induction(i)` via `for` loop for every element in `C_T`. Depends on your problem

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to compare each individual number in the 9x1 matrix to 0.96. Then depending on whether the individual number is greater or less than 0.96, it will perform either equation to every entry in the matrix.

Comment: @Kevin So the code is running fine, but the values of `axial_induction` you suspect might be wrong? Also `axial_induction` would be `9x1` array, right?

Comment: @Divakar The code is running my my answer suggests that the initial axial induction values are being used instead of the calculated values from the if else statement

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare each individual number in the 9x1 matrix to 0.96, you need a `for` loop. If you include the possibility that `C_T` can be also 0.96, it will be simplified to

```
for i=1:length(C_T)
   if C_T(i) <= 0.96;
      axial_induction(i) = 1 / (1+(4*F(i)*(sin(relative_wind(i))^2)) / (sigma(i)*Cl(i)*cos(relative_wind(i)))); 
   else % C_T(i) > 0.96
      axial_induction(i) = 1 / (((4*F(i)*cos(relative_wind(i))) / (sigma(i)*Cl(i)))-1);
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried your suggestion and here is my code:for i=1:length(C_T)
    if C_T(i)<=0.96
        axial_induction(i)=1 ./ (1+(4.*F.*(sin(relative_wind).^2)) ./ (sigma.*Cl.*cos(relative_wind))); 
    elseif C_T(i)>0.96
        axial_induction(i)=1 ./ (((4.*F.*cos(relative_wind)) ./ (sigma.*Cl))-1);
    end
end

Comment: However in the 3rd line of your suggested code i am now getting an error which states: A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Comment: @Kevin I think it would help if you could edit your question with the sizes of the variables.

Comment: @Kevin it works for me. which size has axial_induction?

Comment: I have edited my question to show my current code. Axial induction is a 9x1 matrix

Comment: @kevin now I see that axial_induction is (9x1). Don't define it as axial_induction = 0 at the beginning of your code. It can mislead you

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I deleted that line of code. However I am still getting the following error: In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.

Error in BEM (line 81)
        axial_induction(i)=1 ./ (((4.*F.*cos(relative_wind)) ./ (sigma.*Cl))-1);

Comment: @Kevin you were getting the whole matrix as a result, instead of a single value. Check out my update

Comment: Thanks for the help huys and gals but im still having no luck with it. I tried your code Ironzionlion (exactly as I reposted above) but my programme appears to just ignore it. I'm absolutely baffled?

Comment: @Kevin You are getting stuck in your `while` loop. `abs(Check)>=tolerance` is never true

Comment: @Kevin did my answer solve the problem posted? in that case you can accept it as helpful so other users can identify the answer to your question

Comment: @Kevin So it appears that your loop `while abs(Check)>=tolerance` is never really broken and as such the issue isn't with `IF-ELSE` as claimed in the question and thus voids it. So, I think it would be a good idea to remove the question, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

For a loop approach, check out the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24779412/3293881).

You can vectorize this part of the code like so and this would look close to what you originally had -

```
axial_induction1 = 1 ./ (1+(4.*F.*(sin(relative_wind).^2)) ./ (sigma.*Cl.*cos(relative_wind)));
axial_induction2 = 1 ./ (((4.*F.*cos(relative_wind)) ./ (sigma.*Cl))-1);
cond1 = C_T<=0.96
axial_induction = cond1.*axial_induction1 + ~cond1.*axial_induction2
```

Hope it works for you!